# Unsupported ioctl call in qemu

Tags: qemu, ioctl

Well. I cross compiled the qemu for android and when I use the user mode to run programs, it shows there is an unsupported ioctl call. For example, I ran:

```
./qemu-aarch64 /system/bin/wificond
```

It gives me

```
Unsupported ioctl: cmd=0xffffffffc0046209
Unsupported ioctl: cmd=0x40046205
Binder driver could not be opened.  Terminating.
```

So I think what I may want to do is to add that ioctl call manually. But the problem is I only know the cmd number, how can I figure out what should I add? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to figure out which ioctl it is. This is sadly a bit awkward. One approach would be to eg strace the binary using a native strace, and hope it prints the ioctl symbol for you. Or you can look in the kernel headers for it. Usually ioctls are defined using the _IOC macros in include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h, which constructs them from a set of fields, so you then have to try by guesswork-and-grep to find out the right one from the number. Here 0xc0046209 has a 'type' of 0x62, ie ASCII 'b', and number 0x09, which is

```
#define BINDER_VERSION  _IOWR('b', 9, struct binder_version)
```

(which in fact we could perhaps have guessed from the error message about not being able to open the binder driver).

So what you would need to do here is implement within QEMU emulation of the Android binder API ioctls. Hopefully your host system is also Android, because a non-Android host kernel won't have the binder device.

The difficulty of adding extra ioctls depends a lot on what their parameters are, because the parameters need to be converted from the guest's data layout to the host's. If the ioctl parameters are simple types then it's mostly a matter of providing an IOCTL() line in linux-user/ioctls.h and defining TARGET_IOCTLNAME in linux-user/syscall_defs.h -- for instance upstream QEMU commit d6d6d6fe17fa which adds the RND* ioctls. When the parameter is a struct which is composed of basic types, then things are not much more complicated -- for instance commit 21992cb6794a5f8. In the worst case you need to provide  a custom function to convert the parameters, as seen with TIOCGPTPEER in commit 2b74f621f1c780.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly. I found out that sometimes we don't need to know that target name since all we need to do is having that number defined. So we can just use that unsupported number instead of using _IOWR and save some time . But the point about the parameter is really true.I am facing a struct that has a variant size so seems I need to define some function for that struct.